# Why use anything but uint256/int256 outside of a struct?

Tags: solidity, memory, data-types

I see how uint8 can save space within a struct, but outside of that I do not see any reason to use anything but uint256. The gas cost is slightly higher for uint8.  The only reason I can think of is that you want to ensure users do not generate large numbers, but then any internal checks to make sure you do not have an overflow will already do that.

Not a big deal, but if I'm wrong I suspect I am missing something important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tight packing of storage variables is not unique to structs. From the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage) on the layout of state variables in storage:

> Statically-sized variables (everything except mapping and dynamically-sized array types) are laid out contiguously in storage starting from position 0. Multiple, contiguous items that need less than 32 bytes are packed into a single storage slot if possible, according to the following rules:
>
> - The first item in a storage slot is stored lower-order aligned.
> - Elementary types use only that many bytes that are necessary to store them.
> - If an elementary type does not fit the remaining part of a storage slot, it is moved to the next storage slot.
> - Structs and array data always start a new slot and occupy whole slots (but items inside a struct or array are packed tightly according to these rules).

For non-storage variables, the use of `uint256` (and other 32 byte types) will be cheaper than non 32 byte counterparts as it avoids the need to convert prior to performing calculations:

> When using elements that are smaller than 32 bytes, your contract’s gas usage may be higher. This is because the EVM operates on 32 bytes at a time. Therefore, if the element is smaller than that, the EVM must use more operations in order to reduce the size of the element from 32 bytes to the desired size.

For properly laid out storage variables, the gas savings gained from tight packing more than justify the increased costs due to conversion.

Comment: So just like in structs, I can pack 32 uint8 variables into the storage cost a single uint256 would take?

Comment: Correct.  You might enjoy reading https://medium.com/coinmonks/gas-optimization-in-solidity-part-i-variables-9d5775e43dde for more detailed content about ways to save gas through tight packing.