# Should we use uint64 for storing block.timestamp(instead of uint256)?

Tags: gas

Apparently using uint256 costs less gas on average(if i am not mistaken), but when it comes to storage, using smaller datasize can apparently be cheaper (or so i've heard. is this correct?).

So my question is. Should the timestamp be uint256 or uint64 or even uint40.
Does it optimize for gas and make it cheaper?

```
struct Something {
 .....
 uintX timestamp;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use anything but uint256/int256 outside of a struct?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77153/why-use-anything-but-uint256-int256-outside-of-a-struct)

Comment: It depends on the particular problem. The only way to know for sure is to write the contract and measure gas usage. For most cases with little timestamp usage I'd use uint256, for more heavy use in storage I'd prefer uint64, perhaps mixing both will work in other cases uint64 for storage and uint256 for calculation.

Comment: Related: [Use uint40 for time in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/71366/24693).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think either of *abhinavmir* examples cost more or less. I think they both cost the same.

Variable packing is when you pack several variables that can be added to use 1 memory slot.
A memory slot is a word of 32 bytes.
A string variable will take at least 32 bytes, (+32 bytes again if you go over one 32 bytes limit).

```
uint8
uint8
uint16
uint32
uint64
uint128
```

Would work and take only one memory slot.

However a memory slot will always be filled. So if you use a full memory slot for a uint8, the EVM will automatically fill it with empty bytes to fill up the slot.
In this case using a uint256 is cheaper than using a uint8.

```
uint8
uint256
uint8
uint256
```

is more expensive than 4 uint256.

Using different ints or uints can mainly be for variable packing or limiting the numbers. (Overflow/underflow check...)

Answer (score 0):

The EVM still has to access the slot and read the data contained within it **per value being read**.

As such, whilst 'tightly packed' structs can occupy *less* gas during deployment, when it comes to interacting with the contract, it turns out that actually more gas may be spent whilst trying to read/write/unpack that data content in the slot.

Be careful when optimising in this way, too!

Answer (score 0):

Storage in a solidity pack 32bytes to 1 slot that 32*8=256 bit, so uint8, uint16,... uint256 is the same to use 1 slot in solidity, but when you using uint8 EVM need to downscale from 256bit -> 8bit. So uint8 take more cost than uint256

Comment: `uint8` will take the same amount of gas as `uint256`, if stored in a single storage slot. And if packed will take **less storage**. Regarding reading - it won't downscale, as it will read the required bytes for the uint8.

Comment: **Sorry, indeed the downscaling** makes the difference. `uint8` can consume more gas for that reason.

Answer (score -1):

What you're referring to is tight variable packing.

```
uint256 var1;
uint256 var2;
string abc;
```

Is cheaper than, say -

```
uint256 var1;
string abc;
uint256 var2;
```

This is by design of EVM. `uint256` does not cost "less gas on average". I'd suggest using `uint256` for future proofing. Currently the Unix time stamp is around ~1649302387 - for which `uint32` should suffice, but it will cause overflow in the future. Something to the effect of `false Transaction mined but execution failed` - thus unless important, use `uint256` for `block.timestamp`.

Comment: I want to know if

uint256 is better/cheaper than uint64

uint64 for timestamp will last something like 2billion years(or some high number anyways)

But the question is, is it cheaper to use uint64 or uint256.
I need the variable inside the struct